# Use a single base www directory as the source for multiple platforms?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, cordova

I understand that by doing :

```
phonegap build android
```

a *copy* of the files in `www` is made in `platforms/android/assets/www`

I can then import the platforms/android folder in my IDE as a Android project and run it from there in an emulator or my phone.

But I would like to have only **1 code base** that I can use to build for different platforms, so ideally I would like to be able to make changes to the app in the `www` in the root only.

I guess I need some kind of file-copying builder, that is started before running the project, but I have no experience with this.  I read about Ant, Maven and Gradle....is this the way to go ?

Could anybody tell me how everybody is doing this? Or is it really not common to use 1 single code base for all platforms?  (I thought that was the whole point of Phonegap!)

Answer (score 1):

See PhoneGap 3 project structure for details.  Basically you have folders like:

/merges - for merging/overriding www folder

```
  /android/cordova.js
  /ios/cordova.js
```

/platforms - contain native codes

```
  /android
  /ios
```

/plugins - plugin codes

```
  ... plugin native and stuff
  /www
```

/www - primary folder web app folder

```
  cordojva.js
  index.htm
  etc...
```

Personally, we have not upgraded to PG3, but we follow this same structure.  We use Jenkins on OSX to checkout our files in TFS.  Then we use gruntjs override the www stuff in platforms folder.  Then again, override stuff in platforms folder from merges folder.  Finally, because it is required, we use ant to compile android and xcode to compile iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways each developer follows to have a single code base. In my case, i create two folders Android and Iphone with iphone's www folder being a symlink to the Android's www folder. If i want to have separate script files to be used for iphone and android, i have this code in the index.html file

```
  <!--iPhone 
 <script src="iphone/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
 <script src="iphone/DatePicker.js"></script>

-->
 <!-- android   -->

 <script src="android/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
 <script src="android/datePickerPlugin.js"></script>
```

if i want to run for iphone, i change the comment tags to un comment iphone and comment android

Answer (score 0):

They now have the command line tool that is supposed to solve this problem.
It seems to be a reasonable solution for us.

[cordova command line tool](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)

What we used to do is use SVN and checkout the same folder to 
assets/www for android 
and 
www for iOS

depending on your file structure you may need to have conditional javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var platform = {
            ios: ua.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/),
            android: ua.match(/Android/)
        };
        if (platform.android) {
            document.write('<script src="android/cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/script>');
            document.write('<script src="android/childbrowser.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/script>');
        } else if (platform.ios) {
            document.write('<script src="ios/cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/script>');
            document.write('<script src="ios/ChildBrowser.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/script>');
        }           
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly need of 1 codebase common for all platforms. Phonegap wraps contents in /www folder to make android and iPhone builds out of it.

To copy files from one location to second (if that shows up as a requirement), do give [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) a try. Its an excellent tool to accomplish such tasks.

In my opinion, since phonegap makes its own build, other build tools like ant, maven, gradle can be avoided.